# Git Push command fails in git lab pipeline

Tags: github, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I have created a pipeline to tag and push the commit, I am getting access denied when I push the code to remote origin from the gitlab job.

Note: The script is working fine in the local machine.

```
 - Pushing release to origin
remote: You are not allowed to upload code.
fatal: unable to access 'https://gitlab-ci-token:[MASKED]@xxxxx/xxxx/test_repo.git/': The requested URL returned error: 403
origin
- Switching back to HEAD branch. (restoring local changes)
```

.gitlab-ci.yml

```
build:
  stage: build
  before_script:
    - git config --global user.email "${CI_EMAIL}" && git config --global user.name "${CI_USERNAME}"
  script:
    - bash ./tag-release.sh -b main -t $release
```

Comment: What is in the content of `tag-release.sh`? How are you authenticating? Does the token you're using have push permission?

Comment: the content is here. https://whatthepatch.blogspot.com/2017/06/git-auto-increment-tag.html @sytech

Comment: The script doesn't provide any authentication to git... so it makes sense that the git action is denied.

Comment: I am able to clone the code, not able to push the changes. Can you please help me with git authentication @sytech

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have removed the existing origin settings using
`git remote rm origin`

then added the remote origin with the project access tokens.

```
git remote add origin https://<access-token-name>:<access-token>@gitlab.com/username/reponame.git
```

added the personal access token(GIT_TOKEN_VALUE) and personal access token name(GIT_TOKEN_NAME) in cicd variables and masked/protected it for security purpose.

git remote add command with cicd variable is
`git remote add origin https://${GIT_TOKEN_NAME}:${GIT_TOKEN_VALUE}@gitlab.com/username/reponame.git`

Answer (score 3):

You cannot use the builtin CI token to push to the repo. Instead, you'll need an API token with appropriate scope to push to the repo. A good way to do this is to use [project access tokens](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/settings/project_access_tokens.html). Once you have to token, you can put it in the project CICD variables settings. Then use that API token variable instead of `CI_JOB_TOKEN`.

Comment: I have created a project access token with full access. added as variable in cicd variables. I am getting error still.`Host key verification failed.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.`

Comment: I found it, I have to remove the origin and add with personal tokens. by default, gitlab uses auto generated token(gitlab-ci-token) in the build.